# How to fix server time zone causing exception when trying to connect to MySQL instance with DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, timezone, datagrip

When attempting to connect to a MySQL instance with DataGrip I am receiving a `com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException` exception:

> The server time zone value 'XXX' is unrecognized or represents more than one
>   time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver
>   (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc
>   time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Where `XXX` is my server's timezone (I also love the typo in the exception *specifc*). This error prevents me from creating a connection to the MySQL server. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your server's time zone is not specific. To get around this you need to set the `serverTimezone` property to a value that is specific. The simplest choice is to set it to `UTC` under the Advanced tab:

[image: Advanced Tab serverTimeZone set]

To be clear I'm not sure of the ramifications of this, but it did allow me to connect.

Comment: I deleted my answer about the session time zone because it was irrelevant. You've done everything right, in this settings you need just to help Java to detect the server's time zone because Java cannot do it itself for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem, I tried to replace the driver with 5.1, and the connection was successful:

[image: MySQL 5.1 driver]

Answer (score 0):

Set the time zone yourself in Settings:

[image]